# Finding factors of number and factoring a polynomial (Lua)

Tags: lua

I'm attempting to program with Lua syntax (I have some experience with it) to find the factors of and number and possibly factor an input polynomial. I'm not sure if everyone has done factoring but I learned it by doing a "multiply to" and "add to"/"x-box" method. It'd be interesting to actually draw out the method in Lua (see the picture attached)[image: basically just draw a)] and display the answer. If not to draw, then I'd just use the print command.

I would like the program to have two parameters: one would be the number to determine its prime factors and the other would be the polynomial input (like a, b and c values ax^2+bx+c) to be factored. Then I may also attempt perfect squares and difference of squares.

I'd like some guidance in this and I'm in no way expecting a full working program. Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure what you want here? don't you know how to implement a function in Lua or what is it that stops you from getting started?

Comment: Create list of factors as text string inside `factor()` and display this string inside `draw()`

Comment: This is how I learned to do my factoring, what you did in the picture makes no sense to me. http://pastebin.com/wxB131Ur

Comment: @warspyking The "S= , P=" thing is the X thing in the picture. The top is P and the bottom is S. I see you factored by grouping because it is a complex polynomial (the one in the picture is simple.). In the picture, the b) part is unnecessary; it's just a check.

Comment: For the factors of a number program bit, see [this](http://pastebin.com/ebraaxUh).

Comment: @coding4days Ah, well I think the easiest way to so this would be to simply parse a string that represents a polynomial, and go through each step like in my workings. It wouldn't be hard to code.

Comment: @warspyking Yeah, I'll try and do that. I gotta figure out the most efficient  input method and the rest of the code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Input it with all the terms and coefficients so you don't have to deal with implied coefficients or missing terms, and keep them in standard order ax^2+bx+c

Answer (score 0):

you can make a `for` chunk loop function like this

```
function factor(val)
val=math.floor(val)
found={}
rev={os.time()*4}
halt=0
lastI=0
lastM=0
for m=1,val do
    if halt==1 then
        break
    end
    if lastI == m then
        halt=1
        break
    else
    for i=0,val do
        if m*i == val then
            print(m.."*"..i.."="..val)
            table.insert(found,m.."*"..i)
            table.insert(rev,i.."*"..m)
            lastI=m
            else
        end
    end
end
end
return found
end
```

it will return all posable factors but the downside is it will eventually run back wards but it's not a problem.

> usage example:`factor(6)`
>   returns:`{1*6,2*3,3*2,6*1}`.